# SharePoint Stackexchange promotion on SharePoint Conference 2011 in Anaheim

Tags: discussion, conferences, site-promotion

This is just an idea I had, after talking to my fellow moderators on the site.

We discussed if going out of beta could be timed so that we were going live around the SharePoint Conference 2011, since this would mean we had an extra opportunity to promote the site on SharePoint 2011.

One way of promoting would be to have either a badge or a t-shirt, and then have some price we could offer, for example if you were spotted wearing that badge/tee.

I could talk to some of my friends that have a booth at the conference and hear if we could drop off some Swag there -sort of an underground event on the event.

maybe there are even possibilities for doing some free-style speaking about the site on the information booths in the vendor area?

Any ideas are welcome, so please give me your input on this idea and other ideas for promoting the site on SPC11!

Comment: when is this conference?

Comment: Oct 3rd, but since i travel from europe i leave Oct 1st. Plenty of time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would be more than happy to try and promote the site at the conference.  If we get some stickers or something done up with the new logo in work then maybe we can put them on the badge holder.  That should drive up interest.

Comment: cool mike. whats this badge holder?

Comment: All attendees will have this thing they put around their neck.  It will hold their conference pass with name and location info.  It is  normally about 5-6 inches (13-15cm) and large enough to hang a pin or sticker on.  Christian Glasner for example typically hands out his I heart SP pins.

Comment: Ah ok those. :)